# Is there an easy way or a trick to make layouts in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing... I am trying to make an app for iPhones that encrypts messages. I have finished making the logics of the app(the encrypting part) and just need to make the UI now. Now I have already made it look beautiful on the iPhone 11 with the boundaries and views and everything. I also understand that the app has to work on all devices, and not just the iPhone 11, so I've tried everything. But nothing I've done made it so that it looks good on all supported devices. I don't need it to be look exactly the same on all devices, I'm fine with a usable layout.

Here's how it looks like currently on the iphone SE.
[image: Here's how it currently looks like on the iPhone SE]

And how it's supposed to look like:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This issue has been driving me up the wall for the past few weeks! Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Are the white boxes text fields? text views? Are you laying the elements out in Storyboard? or via code?

Comment: DonMag it was placed it in StoryBoard. Hope that helps! Thanks so much!

Comment: Are the columns of `1` and `0` part of your "background" image? Or are they labels? Edit your question and add just your background image.

Comment: Yes look at swiftui, if you only need to support iOS 13+. As it makes layouts much easier, there are some limitation for complex UI but for the most part should work well with your example.

Comment: The 1s and the 0s are part of the background. Unfortunatey I don't have the background image on me but I will try to explain. The 1s, the 0s, the background color, and the red machine are all part of the background image. The transparent white rectangle is not. I am only supporting iOS 13+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ***LOT*** more to app design than just placing elements on the view. Good UI/UX designers make a lot of money.

I'd suggest reading up and going through several tutorials on Adaptive Layout and how to work with Auto-Layout constraints.

But, this may help you on your way:

[image]

First, I added a `UIImageView` for the background image, and constrained it to all 4 sides of the view. Content Mode is: Aspect Fill

Next, I added a `UIView` to use as the translucent rectangle. Constrained 8-pts to all 4 sides of the **safe-area**.

Then, added a vertical stack view as a subview of the translucent view to hold the text fields and buttons. Stack view settings:

[image]

Stack view is constrained 8-pts Leading and Trailing, CenterY, Height equal to translucent view height with a multiplier of 0.6 (60%).

Next, add 2 text fields and 2 buttons to the stack view.

Top text field gets constraints of Width: equal to stack view width, Height: 80

Second text field gets constraints of Width and Height each equal to top text field Width and Height.

Encrypt button gets Width: equal to stack view width with a multiplier of 0.5 (50%), Height: 44

Save button Width and Height each equal to Encrypt button Width and Height.

This is how it looks on an iPhone 11:

[image]

and how it looks on an iPhone SE:

[image]

Try to follow those instructions to build your own view... play around with the multipliers and heights to get exactly what you want.

Here's the source of the Storyboard if you want to inspect what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="yPA-e8-bF0">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Stack View standard spacing" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="eKS-HH-0an">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="yPA-e8-bF0" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="IMs-mo-OT9">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="enigma" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="a97-39-O1b" userLabel="BkgImageView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                            </imageView>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KU4-QP-gRf" userLabel="TranslucentView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="52" width="398" height="802"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="equalSpacing" alignment="center" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wP8-Q1-mPE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="160.5" width="382" height="481"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Enter password..." textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qfA-Wi-r60" userLabel="Password">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="382" height="80"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="oZi-ie-XZG"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="32"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                            </textField>
                                            <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bjw-4v-4Jx" userLabel="OtherFIeld">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="157.5" width="382" height="80"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99999600649999998" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                            </textField>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bTb-DJ-vCs">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="95.5" y="315.5" width="191" height="44"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="44" id="lf2-w6-UTa"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Encrypt"/>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Cae-UG-Y7N">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="95.5" y="437" width="191" height="44"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Save"/>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="bTb-DJ-vCs" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.5" id="6Wm-3S-qxD"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Cae-UG-Y7N" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="bTb-DJ-vCs" secondAttribute="height" id="p5o-jv-a8L"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="qfA-Wi-r60" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" secondAttribute="width" id="r8a-2n-fea"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Cae-UG-Y7N" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="bTb-DJ-vCs" secondAttribute="width" id="vle-Os-n7x"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="bjw-4v-4Jx" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="qfA-Wi-r60" secondAttribute="width" id="vvF-2z-jNy"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="bjw-4v-4Jx" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="qfA-Wi-r60" secondAttribute="height" id="z1m-rH-13I"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="0.5" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.6" id="Pfn-ju-x0H"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="Q8S-Ar-y5A"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="SGJ-gK-ig4"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="ksD-Lw-Ytc"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="wP8-Q1-mPE" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="wyp-LZ-9UA"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="zyU-KG-DhM"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.2814566791" green="0.56105160710000002" blue="0.5379729271" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="KU4-QP-gRf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="zyU-KG-DhM" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="6jD-v6-UtV"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="a97-39-O1b" secondAttribute="trailing" id="AVi-Gj-Pq8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="zyU-KG-DhM" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="HQF-op-KJr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a97-39-O1b" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="IMs-mo-OT9" secondAttribute="leading" id="JWA-2e-TZN"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="a97-39-O1b" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cQ2-Di-l19"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="a97-39-O1b" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="IMs-mo-OT9" secondAttribute="top" id="csp-iz-KcD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="KU4-QP-gRf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="zyU-KG-DhM" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="rkA-7R-qHD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="zyU-KG-DhM" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="KU4-QP-gRf" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="zbM-iI-Zw9"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="xT8-h3-U8Q" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="303" y="190"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="enigma" width="629" height="1167"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

and here's the background image I whipped up (click for full size)... obviously, replace with yours:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect such a kind and detailed answer! Thanks so much! I'll try this after class and tell you if it worked! Again, thanks so much!